# Смена языков на стороне клиента — JavaScript (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Хочу сделать смену языка на страничке на стороне клиента. Попалась одна статья - [на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/36761/), но примера там уже нет.

Содержимое json файлов как и в примере.

**languages/eng.json**

```
{
"hello_world":"Hello World",
"some_text":"Some Text"
}
```

**languages/rus.json**

```
{
"hello_world":"Привет Мир",
"some_text":"Некоторый текст"
}
```

Код функции из примера:

```
var LANGUAGE;

$.redrawLanguage = function (lang) {
$.ajax({
url : 'languages/' + lang + '.json', //тянем файл с языком
dataType : 'json',
success : function (response) {
LANGUAGE = response; //записываем в глобальную переменную, а вдруг пригодиться
$('body').find("[lng]").each(function () //ищем все элементы с атрибутом
{
var lng = LANGUAGE[ $(this).attr('lng') ]; //берем нужное значение по атрибуту lng
var tag = $(this)[0].tagName.toLowerCase();
switch (tag) //узнаем название тега
{
case "input":
$(this).val(lng);
break;
default:
$(this).html(lng);
break;
}
});
}
});
}
```

В своем примере хочу реализовать данный перевод по клику на соответствующую кнопку RU\EN:

```js
var LANGUAGE = false;
$.redrawLanguage = function (lang) {
  $.ajax({
    url : 'languages/' + lang + '.json', //тянем файл с языком
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function (response) {
      LANGUAGE = response; 
      $('body').find("[lng]").each(function () {
        var lng = LANGUAGE[ $(this).attr('lng') ]; 
        var tag = $(this)[0].tagName.toLowerCase();
        
        console.log(response + ' ' + lng);
        
        
        switch (tag) {
          case "input":
            $(this).val(lng);
            break;
            default:
            $(this).html(lng);
          break;
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

$.getLanguage = function (key) {
  if (typeof(LANGUAGE[key]) != 'undefined') {
    return LANGUAGE[key]; 
  }
  return key; 
}

$('#ru').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var
    $this = $(this);

    $.redrawLanguage('eng');

});

$('#en').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var
    $this = $(this);

    $.redrawLanguage('rus');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<menu>
  <a href="#" class="link" id="ru">RU</a>
  <a href="#" class="link" id="en">EN</a>
</menu>

<p lng="rus">
  Привет Мир
  Некоторый текст
</p>
```

Но ничего не происходит, ошибок нет и json - status 200.

`console.log(response + ' ' + lng);` - выводит `[object Object] undefined`

Как можно запустить перевод на страничке по клику на кнопку, что делаю не так?
Как и с функцией `$.getLanguage`, как ее можно использовать,

> будет нужен для того, что бы иметь возможность в произвольном месте с
>   помощью javascript вынуть нужную строку, текущего языка,

?

Comment: У вас два раза $('#ru').on, может должно быть раз en?

Comment: да раз но не в этом проблема и суть

Comment: `console.log(response);` ?

Comment: @Igor, `console.log(response + ' ' + lng);` - выводит `[object Object] undefined` . Консоль внутри `$('body').find("[lng]")`

Comment: `console.log(response);` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка в html- `<p lng="rus">`, нужно использовать не язык, а ключ - `<p lng="hello_world">`, а функция уже вызывается с соответствующим, нужным языком (имя нужного json файла) - `$.redrawLanguage('eng');` или `$.redrawLanguage('rus');`

```js
var LANGUAGE = false;
$.redrawLanguage = function (lang) {
  $.ajax({
    url : 'languages/' + lang + '.json', //тянем файл с языком
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function (response) {
      LANGUAGE = response; 
      $('body').find("[lng]").each(function () {
        var lng = LANGUAGE[ $(this).attr('lng') ]; 
        var tag = $(this)[0].tagName.toLowerCase();

        switch (tag) {
          case "input":
          $(this).val(lng);
          break;
          default:
          $(this).html(lng);        
          break;
        }
      });


    }
  });
}

$.getLanguage = function (key) {
  if (typeof(LANGUAGE[key]) != 'undefined') {
    return LANGUAGE[key]; 
  }
  return key; 
}


$('#ru').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var
    $this = $(this);

    $.redrawLanguage('eng');

});

$('#en').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var
    $this = $(this);

    $.redrawLanguage('rus');
    console.log($.getLanguage('hello_world') );
    console.log($.getLanguage('some_text') );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<menu>
  <a href="#" class="link" id="en">RU</a>
  <a href="#" class="link" id="ru">EN</a>
</menu>

<p lng="hello_world">
  Привет Мир  
</p>

<p lng="some_text">
  Некоторый текст
</p>



<p lng="hello_world">
  Hello World
</p>



<p lng="some_text">
  Some Text
</p>
```